# Wordpress meta box in specific template file not saving

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, meta-boxes

I seem to have a problem with my meta box saving, not totally sure what I've done wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Heres my functions file:**

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );

function cd_meta_box_add()  
{
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
    $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);

    if ($template_file == 'golf.php')
    {
        add_meta_box ( 
            'golf-times', 
            'Golf Opening Times & Prices', 
            'cd_meta_box_cb', 
            'page', 
            'normal', 
            'high' 
        );
    }
}

function cd_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $times = isset( $values['golf_meta_box_times'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['golf_meta_box_times'][0] ) : '';
    $prices = isset( $values['golf_meta_box_prices'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['golf_meta_box_prices'][0] ) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'golf_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="width: 45%; float: left;">
            <p><label for="golf_meta_box_times">Opening Times</label></p>
            <p><textarea type="text" name="golf_meta_box_times" id="golf_meta_box_times" rows="5" style="width: 90%;" value="<?php echo $times; ?>"> </textarea></p>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 45%; float: left;">
            <p><label for="golf_meta_box_prices">Prices</label></p>
            <p><textarea type="text" name="golf_meta_box_prices" id="golf_meta_box_prices" rows="5" style="width: 90%;" value="<?php echo $prices; ?>"> </textarea></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php   
}


add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'golf_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array(
            'href' => array()
        )
    );

    if( isset( $_POST['golf_meta_box_times'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'golf_meta_box_times', wp_kses( $_POST['golf_meta_box_times'], $allowed ) );

    if( isset( $_POST['golf_meta_box_prices'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'golf_meta_box_prices', wp_kses( $_POST['golf_meta_box_prices'], $allowed ) );

}
?>
```

If anyone has a clue how to make this save it would be a great help!

I am also having issues making the data display - but I can only assume thats where it isnt actually saving haha!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`functions.php` cannot output HTML as far as i know.
wrap your html in a string and return it, your file might be returning errors.

Your add_meta_box code seems to be correct, the condition might not be met, are you sure you are sending data over get?

Comment: I've just done a quick test and it even displays the content from the boxes on the page, it just doesn't seem to save in the admin side of things, the textarea boxes send the data, display it on the front end, but don't save it to the admin end

Comment: Just realised what it is... 
<textarea type="text" name="golf_meta_box_prices" id="golf_meta_box_prices" rows="5" style="width: 90%;" value="<?php echo $prices; ?>"> </textarea>
I've put the data output in the value of textarea, shocking mistake!

Comment: So, what was the solution?